# Relative path for files in different directories?

Tags: html

Let's say I have 3 pages. "index.html", "page1.html" in the folder "pages" and   "page2.html" in "others". So:

- `./index.html`
- `./pages/page1.html`
- `./others/page2.html`

So to link from index.html to page1.html, I have to write:

```
href="./pages/page1.html"
```

But to link from page2.html to page1.html, I have to write:

```
href="../others/page2.html"
```

As the pages increase, managing navigation bar for every one of them gets really 
 painful. Is there a way I can solve this situation for local machine and hosting online? When I did some research, I've found that the solution might be "root path" but that doesn't work in my local machine.

Comment: *the solution might be "root path" but that doesn't work in my local machine.* - Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Also, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: I've tried using "/index.html", "/pages/page1.html" and "/others/page2.html" but that didn't seem to work as the browser fails to find the root directory for my local files. It treats "C://" as the root and goes to "file:///C:/index.html".

Comment: Couldn't use <base> either as it seems to need an absolute path set as the root.

Comment: Check the link I gave you. With BASE in place, you don't start the links with / as the base directory is implied in BASE and all links are relative to it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base - *Absolute and relative URLs are allowed.* - you're expected to google your stuff before you ask on SO.

Comment: But <base> still needs a URL or a path, doesn't it?  Can I write an HTML code that will work on any computer and/or online with <base>?

A code I can put into index.html, page1.html and page2.html in this example and it works without the need of a change.